# ProgressBar into ListBoxItem becomes unselectable while performing steps in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, progress-bar, selectedindex

I have `ListBox` dynamically generated. Each item contains a `ProgressBar` which I can stop, pause or resume by the means of clicking the relative voice on its `ContextMenu`.

Here is the XAML code:

```
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Name="TransfersList" Margin="30,10,-0.444,34.889" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTx}"
                 SelectionChanged="TransfersList_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Ottieni informazioni" Click="GetInfo" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Metti in pausa" Click="PauseTransfer" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Riprendi trasferimento" Click="ResumeTransfer" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Annulla trasferimento" Click="StopTransfer" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ProgressBar Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding NChunks}" Name="gasparino_il_carbonaro"
                                 Value="{Binding PbStatus}" Foreground="{Binding Color}" ToolTip="{Binding TooltipInfo}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

When I click, for example, the `ContextMenu` "GetInfo" voice, I get always the '-1' `SelectedIndex` (even if I have many bars).

I suppose that the problem is due to the `ProgressBar` filling (performing steps and so XAML refreshing), when the `ProgressBar` is filling/refreshing the "system" becomes unable to understand the selected index (which bar I selected with right click?).

My concise question is:

> How can I bind the right-clicked bar with the ContextMenuItem relative
>   method?

Comment: You should be disabling the context menu if there are no selected items. Try your code by clicking on the list box item first, then right clicking to bring up the context menu. You could also create the context menu in the `DataTemplate` instead of on the listbox itself.

Comment: I noticed that when the progress bar is stopped, I can select it and the GetInfo (and other methods) works correctly, but when the progress bar is moving, I lose the selection. How about put the context menu into the DataTemplate?